# Roots and squares in log functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

[image: Math question here]

This is the question I'm trying to solve right now. I know since $x$ is on numerator and $y, w$ are in denominator, they subtracted $y$ and $w$ from $x$. What got me confused is that I have a dim memory of my teacher telling me exponents and roots in the function shouldn't be actual exponents and roots but just multiply them(In example, having cube root means multiply $\frac{1}{3}$ to it and having exponent of $2$ means just multiply $2$ on it.). Am I right on this?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that generally $log_x \space (y^z) = z \space log_x \space y.$ However, it isn't incorrect to write this one way or the other.